# Scraping Google Android Results with phpQuery

Tags: php, web-scraping, phpquery

I scrape the google ranks with this script:

```html
<?php

include("phpQuery-onefile.php");
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&start=1&q=shoes";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($page);

echo $doc['#ires cite'];

?>
```

I get the URL addresses from the Google Snippet (the one under the title in green). He used a library called phpQuery that automates the process. I search for all the "cites" within the Div with the id #ires.

This works perfect the problem starts with the mobile version:

```html
<?php

include("phpQuery-onefile.php");
$url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&output=search&start=1&q=shoes";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1; Mi A1 Build/N2G47H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.83 Mobile Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($page);

echo $doc['#ires cite'];

?>
```

I add the Android agent to the Curl and Google shows the mobile version that has a different styles. Below the title does not appear the address, but the address appears in a similar breadcrumb format.

I can check the positions but not store the complete URL So I would have to get it from the href.

That's my problem, I can't get the complete Url, someone can help me?

I leave a piece of source code of the page of Google mobile version. (snippet)

Thanks in advance

```html
<div>

<a class="C8nzq BmP5tf" href="/url?sa=t&amp;source=web&amp;rct=j&amp;url=https://m.6pm.com/shoes&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjIn8mcosDgAhXxwVkKHT1gDF04ARAWMAB6BAgFEAE&amp;usg=AOvVaw1j59lxT1UHTjMA9CBFqgkQ" oncontextmenu="google.ctpacw.cm(this)">

<div aria-level="3" role="heading" class="MUxGbd v0nnCb">Shoes on Sale | 6pm</div>

<div class="zbELhe MUxGbd lyLwlc aLF0Z">

<span class="qzEoUe">https://m.6pm.com › shoes</span>

</div>

</a>

</div>
```